# Apache2::Request (libapreq2-2.13) on centos 5.5

Tags: linux, perl, installation, apache2, centos

I'm having a torrid time installing Apache2::Request on Centos 5.5.  My apache is the standard one that came with centos.
I'm installing from libapreq2-2.13 and a lot of dependencies didn't already exist.  I so far had to do:

yum install httpd-devel     # for apxs

I then did:

perl Makefile.PL --with-apache2-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs
make

The make step then told me i needed: ExtUtils-XSBuilder and Parse-RecDescent, which i duly installed.

running make again gave the compiler error:

```
/home/xx/installers/libapreq2-2.13/glue/perl/xsbuilder/apreq_xs_postperl.h:22:34: error: modperl_perl_unembed.h: No such file or directory
/home/xx/installers/libapreq2-2.13/glue/perl/xsbuilder/apreq_xs_postperl.h:25:33: error: modperl_common_util.h: No such file or directory
 In file included from Apache2.xs:45:
/home/xx/installers/libapreq2-2.13/glue/perl/xsbuilder/APR/Request/Apache2/APR__Request__Apache2.h:1:22: error: mod_perl.h: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone tell me which package i'm missing?
Is there not a method of installing this common package that "just works" (tm).
Many thanks

Comment: Ok I managed to get this to complete by doing:  yum install mod_perl-devel.   But I now get errors when i actually try and use the package under mod_perl:  `/usr/sbin/httpd: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto/APR/Request/Apache2/Apache2.so: undefined symbol: apreq_handle_apache2`

Comment: ok so i needed to add `LoadModule apreq_module modules/mod_apreq2.so
` to my httpd.conf.  Issue seems to be resolved.

Comment: The question remains though, does anyone know a way to get the above installed in a pain free way on centos 5.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already packaged for Centos.

```
$ repoquery -i --whatprovides 'perl(Apache2::Request)'
perl-libapreq2-0:2.09-0.rc2.1.el5.x86_64

$ sudo yum install perl-libapreq2
```

(Actually, that only works if you're using the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository)

Answer (score 0):

To install the headers , yum install mod_perl-devel